# Excel Vba Method Range.Find

Tags: vba, excel, methods

I had a problem  and Range.Find Method should do the work for it,

On Microsoft site ([Rang.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)), found the code I thought I would need:

```
Set C = wsCountry.Range("G:G").Find(What:="BOSS", MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = C.Address
            Do
               If wsRep.Range("B:B").Find(What:=C.Offset(0, -5), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                    wsUser.Range("SpecialPO").Find(What:="BOSS", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1) = wsUser.Range("SpecialPO").Find(What:="BOSS", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1) + 1
                End If
                Set C = wsCountry.Range("G:G").FindNext(C)

                If C Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While C.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
```

Problem :

When trying to set the variable C for the second time using .FindNext, it will throw value "Nothing". Although the column has another 2 values as "BOSS"

(I found an extent content and probably I will be using another solution suggested by siddharthrout in [Section 3](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). Although I want to know why this solution didn't work as intended)

As always, many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a ` _` after `wsUser.Range("SpecialPO").Find(What:="MASTER SITH", MatchCase:=True`.  I do not know if this is the issue or not but it is a typo.

Comment: Hi Scott. I wanted to cut the text so you guys dont need to move the sidebar. In my code is all in a single line.
The problem only occurs when trying to perform the "Loop While Not..."

Comment: The issue arises when you have a loop, If statement, or a with block that is not properly ended, or is split by another.  Double check that all your blocks have the proper endings and end inside the block that they start.

Comment: I never use .Find (due to it messing up with the user's settings in the Find dialog), but maybe the FindNext must be called on the same range as the original Find was called on?  That is: the original .Find creates a context in which it'll wrap after the last hit, so when you perform a .FindNext on another range outside of the created find context, there's nothing to find for Excel.

Comment: That is exactly what happens... if I switch to a simple c.value change, then the code works fine. Trying concatenate multiple .Find request within the loop gives error. Sort of excel lose the track of what's going on... I've been trying to figure out a work around using .Find method and relocating the ActiveCell but didn't succeed so far :S

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to original question

Question:

> The following line is causing the error.
>
> ```
> Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstAddress
> ```
>
> Error: Object Variable or With Block variable not set.

In VBA, the If/While etc. evaluate all parts of composite conditions (And, Or), unlike in e.g. C++ - i.e., in VBA the And and Or are not short-circuited.  So your first check for Is Nothing doesn't cause the second check on a member to not be performed, hence the Variable not Set error.

The solution is thus to test for Is Nothing separately before checking any members, via a nested If.  This can't be done in the While, so it needs to be done separately before the end of the While loop, and you should store the result in a variable to test for in the While.

Even though the code you posted is from MSDN, it can still be wrong :)

To see this in action, run the following code in a VBA module:

```
Sub x()
  Dim o As Range
  Set o = Nothing
  Do While Not o Is Nothing And o.Address = "whatever"
    Call MsgBox("Made it!")
  Loop
End Sub
```

### Answer to updated question

When you call .Find on a range you create a find context.  This is how .FindNext knows what to find next.  When you 'interrupt' a Find/FindNext sequence with a second (unrelated) .Find (on an unrelated range e.g.), you mess with this context.  The next time you want to continue your .FindNext on your original range, the context will be unusable and the .FindNext will start returning wrong results.  Note that .Find isn't really a nice function to use; it'll actually change the default values in the user's Find dialog.  This also hints to the fact that there's only one Find context in Excel, and it is shared with the user operated GUI (not nice, but what can you do).

See the below code for how this works.  Select an empty sheet, fill it like such:

```
Column A  Column B
a         d
b         e
c         f
a         d
b         e
c         f
```

Then run the code below; it'll show you "Didn't FindNext".  Now comment out the second .Find on oSearchRangeB and run it again; it'll now return "Did FindNext".

```
Sub x()
  Dim oSearchRangeA As Range
  Set oSearchRangeA = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
  Dim oSearchRangeB As Range
  Set oSearchRangeB = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
  Dim oFoundCell As Range
  Set oFoundCell = oSearchRangeA.Find( _
    What:="b", MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
  )
  If Not oFoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Dim oInterferingFoundCell As Range
    Set oInterferingFoundCell = _
      oSearchRangeB.Find(What:="f", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set oFoundCell = oSearchRangeA.FindNext(oFoundCell)
    If oFoundCell Is Nothing Then
      Call MsgBox("Didn't FindNext")
    Else
      Call MsgBox("Did FindNext")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you look at the link the OP provided, that line is directly from the MSDN website.  It will work, there is something else that is wrong.

Comment: Hello Carl, I followed your advise. I have amended the code using a IfStatement to check whether is nothing or not and then exit or keep the loop. Now I know that the variable gives a value of Nothing. Why is so? Shouldn't it check the next "BOSS" value in the column?

Comment: @ScottCraner: then the MSDN documentation is wrong; wouldn't be the first time.  Paste the code I added in my post  in a VBA module and run it; see for yourself.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I see the post has been edited since I replied, and maybe you saw a newer version with the new question; the original I replied to said such a While statement gave the "Object variable or with block not set" error.